# How to install with composer external library that drupal module depends on

Tags: 8, installation, composer, bootstrap-theme

Module [bootstrap_languages](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_languages) depends on external library of [same name](https://github.com/usrz/bootstrap-languages) how do we ask composer to require the external library that needs to go to `libraries/bootstrap_languages` folder

The project's `composer.json` already includes *installer-paths* but how can I make use of them ?

```
    "installer-paths": {
        "core": [
            "type:drupal-core"
        ],
        ....
        "libraries/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-library"
        ]
```

NOTE: the module itself has not taken care of this dependency

Comment: Composer will adhere to them automatically. Example, modules will go to modules/contrib, themes go to themes/contrib, etc, depending on what you have in `installer-paths`.

Comment: so how do I run composer to get the library automatically ? for a module I will say `composer require drupal/devel` but what do I do for an external library ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to include this package via composer by adding some repository info.

Add a package definition to your `repositories` section in your composer.json. The resulting `repositories` section may look like this:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    },
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "usrz/bootstrap-languages",
            "type": "drupal-library",
            "version": "dev-master",
            "dist": {
                "url": "https://github.com/usrz/bootstrap-languages/archive/master.zip",
                "type": "zip"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Then you can just use composer require like:

```
composer require usrz/bootstrap-languages
```

This will add a new line to your `require` section in composer.json like

```
"usrz/bootstrap-languages": "dev-master"
```

Normally I would try to use this approach with a release tag of a package, rather than the master branch, but no tag exists for this repository.

Comment: Hi @sonfd Doing this will load the class in all requests or it will Lazy load the class with autoloading?

Comment: For a different, but similar, example, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/ckeditor/managing-ckeditor-plugins-using-composer

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by using [Asset Packagist](https://asset-packagist.org/). Add **repository** and **installer-types**, **installer-paths** to your `composer.json`

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
    }
],
"extra": {
    "installer-types": ["bower-asset", "npm-asset"],
    "installer-paths": {
        "docroot/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library", "type:bower-asset", "type:npm-asset"]
    },
```

Then you can add package

```
composer require bower-asset/bootstrap-language
```

Comment: Asset Packagist is being adopted by a number of Drupal distros, and contrib modules are now using it as well.  I've just contributed some documentation to officialize this solution https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-manage-drupal-site-dependencies#third-party-libraries and https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/managing-dependencies-for-a-contributed-project#third-party-libraries

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget to add **Composer Installers Extender** by `oomphinc` for the installer paths to work.

```
composer require oomphinc/composer-installers-extender
```

Comment: Thank you, man! It is not working without the extender, I was scratching my head why...